# WPautopop in post_meta

Tags: wordpress, meta

I want allow paragraphs in post_meta of custom type. I think is with WPautopop but how use it in this code? Really thanks

```
<?php $metacontenido = get_post_meta($postid, 'ofertacontenido', true);
    if($metacontenido != $empty) { echo "".$metacontenido.""; }?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `wpautop()` function will automatically convert line endings to `<p>` tags. You can read more about it [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop).

```
<?php $metacontenido = get_post_meta($postid, 'ofertacontenido', true);
      if($metacontenido != $empty) { wpautop($metacontenido); } ?>
```